AppArmor shows active but doesn't seem to be working
I installed the apparmor utilities.  Entered aa-status, got this response:
apparmor module is loaded.
67 profiles are loaded.
65 profiles are in enforce mode.
/home/ironman/data/example.sh
/home/ironman/data/examples.sh
/snap/snapd/21465/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
/snap/snapd/21465/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
/snap/snapd/21759/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
/snap/snapd/21759/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine/...
Tried to run the example in https://pureooze.com/blog/posts/2016-07-28-the-comprehensive-guide-to-apparmor-p1/
created this script:
echo "This is an apparmor example."
touch ./data/sample.txt
echo "File created"
rm ./data/sample.txt
echo "File deleted"
Issued aa-genprof on the script.  Then ran the script in a separate window as genprof asks you to do.  Entered S for scan.  Received this:
Profiling: /home/ironman/examples.sh
Please start the application to be profiled in
another window and exercise its functionality now.
Once completed, select the "Scan" option below in
order to scan the system logs for AppArmor events.
For each AppArmor event, you will be given the
opportunity to choose whether the access should be
allowed or denied.
[(S)can system log for AppArmor events] / (F)inish
Expected to see this:
Reading log entries from /var/log/audit/audit.log.
Updating AppArmor profiles in /etc/apparmor.d.
Profile:  /home/user/bin/example.sh
Execute:  /usr/bin/touch
Severity: 3
(I)nherit / (C)hild / (N)amed / (X) ix On / (D)eny / Abo(r)t / (F)inish
Either apparmor is not logging or not working at all.  Any ideas?

What is the version of Ubuntu you are using and do you know that this example link from 2016 works with the unstated version of Ubuntu?

Version 22.04 LTS

I changed the profile to enforce.  Nothing is authorized, yet the script runs just fine.

When I run under firejail with apparmor enabled access is blocked as expected.  For some reason apparmor is not active by default.  Any ideas?
